# Learning the nested while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

In this program, the inner loop generates random numbers out of 100 and 
    then stops generating them when
    the random number is 7.  The outer loop repeats the inner loop 100 times.
    why doesn't my outer loop keep redoing the inner loop?
    It seems like it only did it once.

```
package test;


public class Loops {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String randomNumberList = " ";
        int c = 0;
        while (c != 100){

            while (i != 7) {
            i = (int) (101 * Math.random());
            sum += i;
            ++counter;
            randomNumberList += " " + i;
            }
        System.out.print("\n loop repeated" + counter+ " times and generated these numbers: " + randomNumberList);
            ++c;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It ran plenty of times for me. I got 100 lines of output. Are you perhaps wondering why the output is the same every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner loop runs until i = 7.  After it finishes, i is still 7, so it won't run again until you change i to some other value.

If you change it to a do - while loop, it should clear up the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Simply because you don't reset `i` before you start the inner loop (or after you end it.)

Therefore, in the second, and subsequent iterations of the outer loop, you get to the inner `while` statement, but the condition `i != 7` is still `false` and you don't execute the inner loop body.

A simple fix would be to add `i = 0` immediately before the inner `while`.

A more elegant fix would be to change the inner `while` into a `do ... while`.

Answer (score 0):

The best fix is to use for loops instead of while loops, and reduce the scope of variables. This results in a cleaner and more idiomatic coding style:

```
import java.util.Random;

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int c = 0; c < 100; ++c) {
        String randomNumberList = " ";
        int sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != 7; ++counter) {
            i = rand.nextInt(101);
            sum += i;
            randomNumberList += " " + i;
        }
        System.out.println("loop repeated " + counter+ " times and generated these numbers: " + randomNumberList);
    }
}
```

Some notes on the above changes:

1. You'll find that the truncated loop was hiding a bug caused by the fact that your variables were initialised only once, before entering the outer loop. The reduced scope of `randomNumberList`, `sum` and `counter` fixes this.
2. It's generally better to print the `\n` at the end of the line, not at the beginning, particularly on Unix, which places the command prompt at the end of the last line of output unless you terminate the last line with a newline. Better still, avoid the problem altogether by using `println`, as shown above.
3. If you want to generate random numbers between zero and 100, `Random.nextInt()` achieves the same result without floating point math and conversions.